# Running ELF file with version mismatch of shared object file

Tags: dll, version, elf

I have an ELF file that links to a shared object file from version X of a library. I only have access to the version of the shared object file from version Y of the library. When I try to run the ELF file, I get `<ELF filename>: <shared object filename>: version X not found (required by <ELF filename>)`. Installing version Y of the library is not an option for me right now. Is there any way to force the ELF file to ignore the version mismatch and try to run? Can I fool the ELF file or somehow edit the shared object file to change the apparent version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The "version" is not the version of the library, but the version of the symbol (ELF files support symbol versioning for keeping backward binary compatibility when changing APIs, see [this post for details](https://flameeyes.blog/2009/04/24/abi-changes-keeping-backward-compatibility/)).

Effectively what it's saying to you is that it's missing a symbol (function, constant, global, etc.) that is not present in the library you have. Which means the library does not have the interface it needs.

Comment: " is not the version of the library, but the version of the symbol" -- you don't _know_ that. Library versions do exist on systems without GNU symbol versioning. However, the particular structure of the message `version X not found (required by ...)` looks like a GLIBC error, so you are  likely correct.

Comment: Or maybe I _do_ know that because that's the error message that is coming out of glibc when that particular situation happens, which is why I said it.